# How to create a cascading list in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

**My Final Expectation:**

I want to have a multi-tiered list in excel so that when I select a **CSP ID** from the drop-down list in excel, it populates the columns - **CSP first-name** and **CSP last-name**  adjacent to the column **CSP ID**.

So for example : If *1742329* is the *CSP ID* corresponding to which I have a CSP fname as *Andrea* and CSP lname as *Rogers*, so on selecting the CSP ID in the excel drop down list it should automatically populate the CSP fname and CSP lname.

**My Current Situation:**

After looking at a lot of tutorials and web links I could not find help since in my case a CSP ID will always correspond to a Unique CSP First-name and last-name

Please look at the screenshots below :

[Here is a list of all the CSP IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6yI5.png)

[Here is a list of all the CSP Last Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzhEk.png)

[Here is a list of all the CSP First Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqbhr.png)

**Note**: This drop-down list is for the entire column and not just the first row.

You can see the list is very long so I cannot follow the method shown on the internet. So I need an approach to solve this problem.

Also on a separate sheet, I will be having a list of all the CSP ID corresponding to their First and Last name. [Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQw26.png)

Comment: I'm confused as to where the cascading dropdown list is in your description. It sounds like you want just a normal drop down for CSPID and then a simple `VLOOKUP` to get the first and last names for that ID...? So what I'm saying is DONT have drop downs in the first and last name columns, but instead have a formula doing a simple `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Hey i just found what you said but now i am facing an issue as to how can i implement for the entire coloumn. If i just select a csp id then csp fname, csp lname should be auto populated. Do you have any useful links that could help me with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a cascading dropdown. You need a single dropdown for your ID column and then just a regular `VLOOKUP` for both your fname and lname columns. Then you just drag the `VLOOKUP` formula down. If you want, pre-populate a bunch of rows (say maybe the first 1000 rows).

Let's assume your ID is in column A and you have a header row. I'll also assume you have a lookup table on a sheet called lookup where ID is in column A and first name is in column B. Now instead of a dropdown in your fname column, use the formula:

```
=IF(A2<>"", VLOOKUP(A2, 'lookup'!A:B,2,0), "")
```